# Extra destructor called in vector of class object

Tags: c++

```
TestDelete::TestDelete(int i) {
    this->i = i;
    std::cout <<"TestDelete constructor for "<<this->i<<"\n";
}

TestDelete::~TestDelete() {
    std::cout <<"TestDelete destructor for "<<this->i<<"\n";
}

int main () {
  std::vector<TestDelete> pt;
  pt.push_back(TestDelete(1));
  pt.push_back(TestDelete(2));

  return 0;
}
```

The above code snippet outputs as below

> TestDelete constructor for 1
>
> TestDelete destructor for 1
>
> TestDelete constructor for 2
>
> **TestDelete destructor for 1**;
>
> TestDelete destructor for 2;
>
> TestDelete destructor for 1;
>
> TestDelete destructor for 2;

I understand the implementation of `push_back` is based on copy-swap concept, due to which the constructor and destructor of the temperory object is called. But if you notice an extra call to destructor of `object1` is made.

Can someone explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 2):

You are breaking the [Rule of 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) and one of your objects is getting copied and you are seeing the destructor of that copy.

If you add a copy constructor and an copy assignment operator with logging you'll see understandable behavior.

EDIT: As people are getting confused by this answer in the comments - this is just meant to show that nothing is going *wrong*, just that if you add CC/CAO with logging you'll see all you objects get correctly created/assigned/destroyed. CC/CAO isn't needed for program correctness. There's a better answer below on why std::vector may be creating/assigning/destroying in the order you see below. Apologies for any confusion caused.

Comment: The Rule of 3 is outdated. The [Rule of 0](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html) is the new hot stuff. No really, why would this be important here? Also, AFAIU, the Rule of 3 is only important in the case of pointer data members.

Comment: If you need a destructor (which he *does* for understanding, not for any real reason) then you also need a CC/CAO. The Rule of 3 states that *if* you need one of the 3 you need all. Not that you must have any.

Comment: Can you give me a reason other than "the rule of three says so" in this case (no pointer data members), for which the compiler cannot handle generating the correct member function bodies?

Comment: Huh? The auto generated one wont log and show that object with id 1 is being copied and therefore the second destructor for an object with id 1 isn't a compiler/library bug but actually destroying the copy. Without adding one himself with logging he gets the confusing output which makes it seem like the same object is being destroyed twice.

Comment: so you agree the only reason to add the copy constructor is to see better what's going on and not satisfy the text-book rule of 3?

Comment: He has a destructor with non-default observable behavoir. Now the observer is actually a human reading the log rather than some other part of his program which is more traditional. However, that in no way negates the need for the rule of 3 - the observer is getting confused in this case for exactly the reason the rule of 3 exists and using the rule of 3 solves it. [and yes I understand that adding the CC/CAO doesn't change the semantics of the program, nor is it required for program correctness]

Comment: Mike Vine is right. There are extra TestDeletes that are being copy constructed but not logged in this example.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see what your implementation might be doing:

```
std::vector<TestDelete> pt;
```

Creates a vector with size 0.

```
pt.push_back(TestDelete(1));
```

Reallocates the vector with size 1. Adds new element by copy-constructing (move-constructing) the temporary.

```
pt.push_back(TestDelete(2));
```

Reallocates vector with size 2. This means copy-constructing (or move-constructing) the previously created element, and deleting the original. Adds a new element by copy-constructing (move-constructing) the temporary.

[Here is a live example](http://ideone.com/M9R6Kg), also featuring an improvement, which prevents the vector from reallocating. Note that the temporaries are still being destructed, which surprises me; I'd guess the compiler can elide the copies.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of `std::vector`'s resize policy. Then it gets filled, it grows by some factor. This requires new memory allocation + old memory deallocation (*and thus destructor's invocation*).

For example, if you reserve memory beforehand, resize won't happen:

**$ cat main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class TestDelete {
public:
        TestDelete(int);
        ~TestDelete();

        int i;
};

TestDelete::TestDelete(int i) {
    this->i = i;
    std::cout <<"TestDelete constructor for "<<this->i<<"\n";
}

TestDelete::~TestDelete() {
    std::cout <<"TestDelete destructor for "<<this->i<<"\n";
}

int main () {
  std::vector<TestDelete> pt;

  pt.reserve(10); // reserve memory for 10 objects
  pt.push_back(TestDelete(1)); // so no resize would be needed
  pt.push_back(TestDelete(2));

  return 0;
}
```

**$ ./a.out**

```
TestDelete constructor for 1 // temporary object constructed
TestDelete destructor for 1  // temporary object destructed
TestDelete constructor for 2  // temporary object constructed
TestDelete destructor for 2  // temporary object destructed
TestDelete destructor for 1  // vector destructed
TestDelete destructor for 2 // vector destructed
```

Comment: Thank you all for your response. Though I got the solution to correct this behavior by reserving memory for object, I am still unable to understand the Resize Policy that is mentioned above. Please suggest me some reference for detailed understanding on STL vector's memory allocation and deallocation. Thank You in advance.

Comment: I don't know any articles on it, but [that one](http://www.frogatto.com/?p=26) seems to be ok.